# Android Studio - Is there any way to add the Module direct from git/svn without storing it locally

Tags: android, android-studio

Generally we download module from git or any version control, store it locally and add this as a module dependency. So everytime if there is any  changes on module, I have to pull and update the existing one locally.
Is there any way to add the Module direct from git/svn and if there is any changes(commit) on module, it will reflect automatically?

Comment: Why not? If you change any mode you can directly commit and push on git and also directly update from git in android studio.

Comment: [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)?

Comment: Are you referring to third party libraries? You can use gradle dependencies to pull in these modules, without having to store the code for them in the VCS.

Comment: @SteveEdson It is  3rd party module.  How? Can you please give me any link.

Answer (score 1):

To include third party libraries into your application, without having to add the source to your version control, you can use third party dependencies.

For example, the Picasso Library from square (http://square.github.io/picasso/) can be loaded in with `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`. This goes in the dependencies block in your `build.gradle` config.

To update to a later version, you simply change the `2.5.2` to the required version number.

This is also where you can (or might be doing already) include Google Play Services, and the Android Design and Support libraries.

For more information, see here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup.

Comment: I am sorry , I think my question is not clear. Suppose I have created a library and have pushed to git. Now My original project will use that library. But I don't want to download my library. It will directly connect to library git url. How?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. You can reference the library using a git submodule, so that it is easier to maintain, however it would still need to be sat in the projects folder. What is the specific problem with this? If we know that, we might be able to address that specific issue.